# Google Chrome "Failed to load resource"

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, console, image

I am using a watermarking system to protect all my photos on my page:

```
<?php
$imagesource = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."**path**".$_GET['path'];
if (!file_exists($imagesource)) die();
$filetype = strtolower(substr($imagesource,strlen($imagesource)-4,4));
if($filetype == ".gif") $image = @imagecreatefromgif($imagesource); 
if($filetype == ".jpg") $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imagesource); 
if($filetype == ".png") $image = @imagecreatefrompng($imagesource); 
if (empty($image)) die();
$watermark = @imagecreatefrompng('watermark_'.(imagesx($image) <= 1100 ? "port" : "lans").'.png');
$imagewidth = imagesx($image);
$imageheight = imagesy($image); 
$watermarkwidth = imagesx($watermark);
$watermarkheight = imagesy($watermark);
$startwidth = (($imagewidth - $watermarkwidth)/2);
$startheight = (($imageheight - $watermarkheight)/2);
imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $startwidth, $startheight, 0, 0, $watermarkwidth, $watermarkheight);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
?>
```

This works fine, however when I load this page in Google Chrome the images pre-load and display but as soon as they render Chrome says "Failed to load resource". Which is strange because if you failed to load it why were you displaying it then?

Anyways I cannot replicate this issue on any other browser. Which is again strange, this tells me that there is nothing wrong with the script.

I have been noticing the smaller the images I have the more display correctly, but what good is 2 out of 19 images loading!!

Now this does not happen when i display the images normally (i.e. without the watermarking script. through "<"img"><"/img">" tags)

But on another website I have there is no watermarking script, but they still do not load.

Another question I have is;

I have to use copyright and .htaccess protection on the original files because of the laws governing my website contract... Anyway so the user cannot access the image source files directly. Could these errors be a result of this? But then again why would some display and others not, and in the same way why is it only Google Chrome that has this issue?

Your thoughts would be appriciated.

P.S. this is my browser info:

```
Google Chrome   19.0.1084.56 (Official Build 140965) m
OS  Windows
WebKit  536.5 (@119244)
JavaScript  V8 3.9.24.29
Flash   11,3,300,257
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
```

Visual Example:

[image: Loading]

[image: Loaded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in chrome. Been driving me crazy ended up coming up with a "fix" using base64. Leave your watermarking script exactly the same and go into the script that is outputting the images.

```
function base64_encode_image ($imagefile) {
      $filename=htmlentities($imagefile);
      $filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $imgbinary = file_get_contents($filename);
      return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
}

$string=base64_encode_image("http://www.domain.com.au/watermark.php?imagesrc=image1.jpg");

$imgList.="<img src=\"$string\" title=\"\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is due because you don't give back the Content-Lentgh.

You have to replace the line  `imagejpeg($image);` with the following code:

```
    imagejpeg($image, 'php://memory/temp.jpeg'); 
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize('php://memory/temp.jpeg'));
    $fp = fopen("php://temp/temp.jpeg", 'r');
    echo stream_get_contents($fp);
```